# Inline video playback solution for iPhone and Android?

Tags: iphone, android, video, animation, inline

I'm looking for a way to play videos, or rather, show a frame-by-frame animation with the built-in web browsers of iPhone and Android devices.

Conditions:

- It must be played **inline** on the **built-in mobile web browsers**
- The videos are 240x240 in size and around 10 seconds in length

  - They were originally .swf files containing Flash animation

HTML5 video tag is disqualified because there is only fullscreen playback on iPhone devices.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need a mobile phone solution, or you have access to a web page?
You can always try to use timed javascript to switch images with a set interval.

Comment: My requirement was to use only HTML/CSS/JavaScript. In my case, I went with manually recreating each sprite's animation movement with jQuery. A solution along your suggestion can be found in [How is Stackoverflow doing the animation on vote UP or Down](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85641/how-is-stackoverflow-doing-the-animation-on-vote-up-or-down)

Answer (score 0):

maybe, you could try using the image and update your web browser every time, but it's probably very ugly solution;